# DNS name from NetBIOS name - API function

Tags: c++, winapi, vb6, ldap, adsi

Is there **any API function** that can resolve **netbios** name of a user or group directory object.

I need output in following formats:

1. **NameFullyQualifiedDN**  - example: CN=John Smith,OU=Users,DC=Engineering,DC=Microsoft,DC=Com
2. **NameDnsDomain** - example: engineering.microsoft.com\JSmith
3. Any other format that gives DNS domain name.

**NOTE** : TranslateName function is failing while giving name as shown below: **win2008domainnetbiosname\username**.

Thanks

Comment: How does `TranslateName` fail? what arguments are you passing to `TranslateName`?

Comment: I am passing NameSamCompatible to translatename. Please see NOTE in description for an example and asking for NameFullyQualifiedDN. It works fine for if i give a windows 2003 domain user SamCompatible name. My user account is on windows 2003 domain which has bi-directional trust relationship with windows 2008 domain.

Comment: I can't test any of this, so won't submit this as an answer, but I suggest you take a look at [`DsCrackNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675970(VS.85).aspx) or possibly [`IADsNameTranslate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706046(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: IADsNameTranslate worked for me. Thanks a lot, Hasturkun.

Comment: Hi, Why do you not put a formal answer in order to make me mark it correct? I was thinking you should get credit for your efforts.

Comment: I posted an answer just now, I just don't think it's very good (as it lacks depth). All I did was search through the documentation for similar functions, though

Comment: I m sorry i could not see your posted answer earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`IADsNameTranslate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706046%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [`DsCrackNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675970%28VS.85%29.aspx) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [`GetAddrInfoW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738519%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function. Try to use it by the following service names:

```
netbios-ns        137/tcp    nbname                 #NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns        137/udp    nbname                 #NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-dgm       138/udp    nbdatagram             #NETBIOS Datagram Service
netbios-ssn       139/tcp    nbsession              #NETBIOS Session Service
```

An example could be found on the [MSDN page of `GetAddrInfoW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738519%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

When you get the correct answer, use [`DnsHostnameToComputerName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724244%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

[More info on computer names (MSDN).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724220%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IADsNameTranslate or DsCrackNames are not able to get this name format:

NameDnsDomain - example: engineering.microsoft.com\JSmith

if you take a look at the [DS_NAME_FORMAT Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ntdsapi/ne-ntdsapi-ds_name_format) of DsCrackNames or [ADS_NAME_TYPE_ENUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/ne-iads-__midl___midl_itf_ads_0001_0050_0001) of IADsNameTranslate, you would get to know the second name format couldn't be achieved by the two apis